# How to reset a Susy container?

Tags: susy-compass

What is the best method to reset a Susy grid container? I have a grid with a couple of containers under each other, like this:

```
+-----------------+
|   [container]   |
|   [container]   |
|   [container]   |
|                 |    
+-----------------+
```

Now on the front page, I want one container to be full width:

```
+-----------------+
|   [container]   |
|[   container   ]|
|   [container]   |
|                 |    
+-----------------+
```

Currently I am resetting the container like this:

```
body.front {
  #main {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
}
```

However, seeing that Susy already contains reset mixins like `reset-columns` I'm wondering if this is the recommended way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is right. There is no reset-container mixin currently.

Comment: So may one consider to use the #main rules above as a 'neutralize-containers' mixin? Could we safely rely on it?

Comment: It looks about right, and for this major version (Susy 2) it will remain reliable.  The best way to check for sure is to look at the output CSS from the container mixin, and override whatever part you need to. My general preference, though, is to avoid overrides and find a way to apply the container mixin more narrowly in the first place. That's the most reliable solution.